# Does XMPP allow users to send messages through someone elses server?

Tags: xmpp

I was looking at this page: https://list.jabber.at , which states that everyone can use the public servers on that page for free.

But then how does one register an account to send messages to ? How will all the servers know about the account, and how does one authenticate it ?

EDIT: Also, how does one prevent creating duplicate accounts ? It seems "in-band" registration allows registering using the protocol itself, instead of a centralised server. But how does everyone know about it then ?